# Filter object by its members

Tags: guava

I'm trying to filter an object in Guava. For example I have a class Team and would like to get all the teams with position below 5.

```
    Iterable<Team> test = Iterables.filter(teams, new Predicate<Team>(){  
        public boolean apply(Team p) {  
            return p.getPosition() <= 5;  
        }  
    });
```

I'm getting 2 errors, Predicate cannot be resolved to a type and The method filter(Iterable, Predicate) in the type Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (List <'Team'>, new Predicate<'Team'>(){}).

I'm able to filter Iterables of type Integer.

```
    Iterable<Integer> t6 = Iterables.filter(set1, Range.open(0, 3));
```

How do i filter an object based on its members in Guava ? I want to use this library in my android project and have many filtering conditions. Can it be used for class objects or is it only for simple data types ?

Comment: It can be used for any objects, and did you import Predicate from com.google.common.base?

Comment: yes predicate has also been imported in the guava jar.

Comment: Hi Louis.. You were right. I had only imported Predicates and not Predicate. Please leave an answer so i can mark it as correct.

Comment: What's the point of `Iterable<Integer> t6 = Iterables.filter(set1, Range.open(0, 3));` ? (your code not compile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `final` variable like `range` in this example.

This is the way to filter with external parameters, Predicate is an inner class.

```java
final Range range = new IntRange(0, 3);

Iterable<Team> test = Iterables.filter(teams, new Predicate<Team>() {
    public boolean apply(Team p) {
        return range.containsInteger(p.getPosition());
    }
});
```